# Networking, MST between HPE and CISCO switches

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, hpe

can anybody help with this issue?

I have 2 HP Procurve switches 2650 and one Cisco switch 2950 connected together like this:
HP MST root (prio 16384) <-> HP IST root (prio 24576) Trk1 <-> Po1 Cisco IST member (prio 32768). 
There is a MSTP configured on all of them.
My problem is that the Cisco switch claims itself to be the IST master:

```
C2950C24_01#show span mst

###### MST00        vlans mapped:   1-4094
Bridge      address 000a.b7b8.4e40  priority  32768 (32768 sysid 0)
Root        address 0015.6033.dc00  priority  16384 (16384 sysid 0)
            port    Po1             path cost 120000
IST master  this switch
Operational hello time 2, forward delay 7, max age 12
Configured  hello time 2, forward delay 7, max age 12, max hops 20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/4            Desg FWD 200000    128.4    Edge P2p
Fa0/5            Desg FWD 200000    128.5    Edge P2p
Fa0/8            Desg FWD 200000    128.8    Edge P2p
Fa0/9            Desg FWD 200000    128.9    Edge P2p
Fa0/10           Desg FWD 200000    128.10   P2p
Fa0/11           Desg FWD 200000    128.11   Edge P2p
Fa0/13           Desg FWD 200000    128.13   Edge P2p
Fa0/14           Desg FWD 200000    128.14   Edge P2p
Fa0/15           Desg FWD 200000    128.15   Edge P2p
Fa0/17           Desg FWD 200000    128.17   Edge P2p
Fa0/18           Desg FWD 200000    128.18   Edge P2p
Fa0/20           Desg FWD 200000    128.20   Edge P2p
Fa0/21           Desg FWD 2000000   128.21   Edge Shr
Fa0/22           Desg FWD 200000    128.22   Edge P2p
Po1              Root FWD 100000    128.65   P2p Bound(RSTP)

C2950C24_01#
```

Even if it receives BPDUs from the middle HP switch that has got lower prio.
(Lets ignore now the MST root - left HP switch)

```
C2950C24_01#sh spanning-tree det

 MST00 is executing the mstp compatible Spanning Tree protocol
  Bridge Identifier has priority 32768, sysid 0, address 000a.b7b8.4e40
  Configured hello time 2, max age 12, forward delay 7
  Current root has priority 16384, address 0015.6033.dc00
  Root port is 65 (Port-channel1), cost of root path is 120000
  Topology change flag not set, detected flag not set
  Number of topology changes 14 last change occurred 09:52:38 ago
          from Port-channel1
  Times:  hold 1, topology change 19, notification 2
          hello 2, max age 12, forward delay 7
  Timers: hello 0, topology change 0, notification 0

.
.
 Port 65 (Port-channel1) of MST00 is root forwarding
   Port path cost 100000, Port priority 128, Port Identifier 128.65.
   Designated root has priority 16384, address 0015.6033.dc00
-->  Designated bridge has priority 24576, address 001f.281e.4100
   Designated port id is 64.51, designated path cost 20000
   Timers: message age 4, forward delay 0, hold 0
   Number of transitions to forwarding state: 1
   Link type is point-to-point by default, Boundary RSTP
   BPDU: sent 36733, received 18973

C2950C24_01#
```

Here is the output from the middle HP switch:

```
  H2650G48_12# sh span
  Multiple Spanning Tree (MST) Information
  STP Enabled   : Yes
  Force Version : MSTP-operation
  IST Mapped VLANs : 1-4094
  Switch MAC Address : 001871-218080
  Switch Priority    : 32768
  Max Age  : 12
  Max Hops : 20
  Forward Delay : 7
  Topology Change Count  : 659
  Time Since Last Change : 10 hours

  CST Root MAC Address : 001560-33dc00
  CST Root Priority    : 16384
  CST Root Path Cost   : 20000
  CST Root Port        : 49
  IST Regional Root MAC Address : 001f28-1e4100
  IST Regional Root Priority    : 24576
  IST Regional Root Path Cost   : 20000
  IST Remaining Hops            : 19
  Root Guard Ports :
  TCN Guard Ports  :
  BPDU Protected Ports :
  BPDU Filtered Ports  :
  PVST Protected Ports :
  PVST Filtered Ports  :
                 |           Prio             | Designated    Hello
  Port Type      | Cost      rity  State      | Bridge        Time  PtP Edge
  ---- --------- + --------- ----- ---------- + ------------- ----- --- ----
  .
  .
  Trk1           | 200000    64    Forwarding | 001871-218080 2     Yes No
H2650G48_12#
```

Here are the running-configs of the Cisco and the middle HP switch.
What could be wrong there ??

```
    C2950C24_01#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 5237 bytes
!
version 12.1
.
.

spanning-tree mode mst
no spanning-tree optimize bpdu transmission
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
spanning-tree mst configuration
 name LKN1
 revision 1
!
```

The middle HP switch:

```
H2650G48_12# sh run

Running configuration:

; J4899B Configuration Editor; Created on release #H.10.119
.
.
trunk 45-46 Trk1 LACP
. 
.
spanning-tree
spanning-tree protocol-version MSTP
.
.
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
spanning-tree config-name "LKN1"
spanning-tree config-revision 1


H2650G48_12#
```

Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

Your priorities tie so lowest mac wins which is Cisco.

**Cisco**

```
  Bridge Identifier has priority 32768, sysid 0, address 000a.b7b8.4e40
```

**HPE**

```
  Switch MAC Address : 001871-218080
  Switch Priority    : 32768
```

I'd have to lab this one up to confirm, but I suspect you can resolve by issuing by lowering your trk1 priority to 2 or 3 on the HPE or force the priority on the instance.

```
spanning-tree instance 1 priority 1
```